# Azure Machine learning pipeline - Azure Databricks as compute target

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-cloud-services, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using Azure Databricks as a compute target from Azure Machine Learning Pipeline with a DatabricksStep
to run a Python script that is available on a compute instance that works as my development workstation (will upload to DBFS, and then run in Databricks). All worked fine until yesterday morning (Italian time) but since then it began to take hours for the pipeline only to start and after running in some case the run completes successfully while in other cases it failed with the error below (from Azure ML execution logs file). I've also updated Azure ML Python SDK version from 1.14.0 to 1.15.0 with no improvement.

```
[2020-10-05 12:55:30Z] Parsed interface. Will be submitting job to Azure Databricks adb-3647409015056007.7.azuredatabricks.net
[2020-10-05 12:55:36Z] Failed to submit job because of error: Unable to get module b436d4a1-3cc7-4382-a1ac-29bde5d24cb3: Microsoft.RelInfra.Common.Exceptions.OperationFailedException: Unable to download resource from , exception: Microsoft.RelInfra.Common.Exceptions.OperationFailedException: Cannot download resource. ---> Microsoft.RelInfra.Common.Exceptions.ServiceInvocationException: Failure in GetSnapshotFilesZipSas while calling service Snapshot; HttpMethod: GET; Response StatusCode: ; Exception type: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException|-System.IO.IOException|-System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: are you still seeing this error? It looks like a backend service failure to me....

Comment: still today unacceptable time for a pipeline to even start...no improvements for two days now